# Frontend and backend separation and deploy best approach - azure

Tags: azure, deployment

I have separated frontend and backend projects. What is the best approach to deploy them? Is it possible to have them under same domain?

I want to know what is the best + simple approach to deploy both of them, having in the same domain or create a subdomain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple alternatives.

If you're using SPA frameworks in the frontend, you can deploy it as static web app, and your backend to webapp. They will belong to different domains, but you can leverage some CDN platform to deliver the front end content and boost the performance.

You can also containerize everything and deploy into a Web App for containers. Those I believe are the easiest ways.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what about creating a subdomain? For example: mysite.com for frontend and api.mysite.com? Is not better than having them under different domains?

Comment: you can create subdomains and point to web app